# How can I solve the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{((-1)^n+5)^{1/n}}{3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I solve the limit ($n \in \mathbb{N}$): $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{((-1)^n+5)^{1/n}}{3}$$Is it ok to say that it is greater or equal to $\frac{4^{1/n}}{3}$ and lower or equal to $\frac{6^{1/n}}{3}$ and thus the limit $=\frac{1}{3}$ ?

Comment: $-1\le\lim_{x\to\infty}(-1)^x\le1\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}((-1)^x+5)^{1/x}\to C^{1/x}=1$ where $C$ is some finite constant

Comment: @Dinas: It would be better you edit your post putting $n$ instead of $x$.Do you know solve $x=(-1)^{0.43}$, for instance?

Comment: Yes, except it is $(4/3)^{1/x}$. I would prefer $n$ as the name of the variable.

Comment: @AlexM:  When I made my comment there was a $3^{1/x}$ at the bottom. There has been significant editing since.

Comment: Sorry this is the final form

Comment: @Dinas Thank you for correcting the discrepancy in your question promptly. I have on more than one occasion found one of my answers downvoted a day or two after making it due to the fact that the questioner changed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your sequence in two subsequences, corresponding to $n$ even and, respectively, $n$ odd. For even $n$, your quantity becomes $\dfrac {6^{\frac 1 n}} 3$ which, indeed, tends to $\frac 1 3$. For odd $n$, the quantity is $\dfrac {4^{\frac 1 n}} 3$ which, again, tends to $\frac 1 3$. Therefore, your quantity tends to $\frac 1 3$.

Your argument based on inequalities is equally valid.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^{1/n}}{3}$

Comment: @Dinas As $n\to \infty$ , $4^{1/n}\to 1$

Comment: So $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^{1/n}}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$ ?

Comment: that's right @Dinas

Comment: @Dinas: If $n \to \infty$, then $\frac 1 n \to 0$, so $4^{\frac 1 n} \to 4^0 = 1$. Putting the denominator gives $\frac 1 3$, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Note:
Here's how to show that
$a^{1/n}
\to 1
$
for $a > 1$.

Since
$a > 1$,
$a^{1/n} > 1$.
Therefore
$a^{1/n} = 1+b$
with
$b > 0$.

Raising to the
$n$-th power,
$a = (1+b)^n
$.

By Bernoulli's inequality
(easily proved by induction),
$(1+b)^n
\ge 1+nb
$.
Since
$b = a^{1/n}-1
$,
we have

$\begin{array}\\
a
&=(1+b)^n\\
&\ge 1+nb\\
&=1+n(a^{1/n}-1)\\
\text{so}\\
a^{1/n}
&\le \dfrac{a-1}{n}+1\\
\text{or}\\
a^{1/n}-1
&\le \dfrac{a-1}{n}\\
&\to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$